# React + modal: input field auto focus

Tags: reactjs, autofocus

I'm using `React` and `Ant Design`.

I have a popover with a button. When the user clicks the button, it shows the modal with an input field.

**Problem**

When I click the Show Modal Button auto focus is not working and also popover is not hiding

I tried with HTML5 `autoFocus`

```
<textarea autoFocus></textarea>
```

But it did not work, here the code: [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-beveqs)

Comment: Maybe this can help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42853176/html5-textarea-autofocus-attribute-inside-modals-does-not-working

Comment: What are you trying to set focus to? I don't see a `<textarea />` anywhere in your code

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-beveqs I have updated link

Comment: @MariaJeysinghAnbu, I have added an answer. Let know if that helped.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you show Modal, you can use `ref` of your `textarea` to manually set focus.

```
 showModal=()=> {
    this.setState({
        visible: true,
        popOverVisible: false
    },()=>{
      setTimeout(()=>{this.testInput && this.testInput.focus()}, 1);
    });
 }
```

In Your Modal,

```
<Modal ...>
  ...
  <textarea 
   type='text'
   ref={(textarea) => { this.testInput = textarea; }} ></textarea>
  ...
</Modal>
```

To hide you Popover, you can use `visible` prop of `PopOver` and set state accordingly.

```
 showPopOver = () => {
    this.setState({
      popOverVisible: true
    })
 }
 ...
 <Popover ...
   visible={this.state.popOverVisible}>
   <span type="primary" onClick={this.showPopOver}>Click me (Popover Button)</span>
 </Popover>
```

Hope this helps.

[Working demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-9wzvxm?file=index.js)

For multiple PopOvers : [Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-bexnl1?file=index.js)

Comment: Thanks @Dev. It is not working when there are two popover buttons. at the same time both popover button are showing

Comment: How many Popovers you are going to have? If you are going to reuse them, I would suggest change visibility of popovers by appropriately setting the state. Let me update the answer

Comment: @MariaJeysinghAnbu, Updated the answer. Hope this helps

Comment: It worked for me, but I don't understand the logic. Do you have a link to documentation of this ref attribute and second argument of setState?

Comment: it didn't work for me. Just a waste of time. 
console.log(this.testInput); // undefined

Comment: This also be working(I haven't tried it), but the answer by @Rosy Shrestha worked & it was simple as putting a HTML attribute to the input element inside of the modal, Can you clarify the difference between React's `useRef` hook & this https://stackoverflow.com/a/53648011/12204242 answer? Does it have any issues in the context of React?

Answer (score 21):

Add **autoFocus={false}** to your modal to reject the modal's focus management.

```
<Modal ... autoFocus={false}>

<textarea autoFocus={true}>
```

Comment: After opening a modal I'm loading a tinymce editor inside modal. When any of the tinymce modal is opened on top of the bootstrap modal none of the tinymce modal input controls are getting focused. Tried setting autoFocus to false on Modal but still no use. Any other solution

Comment: This worked like a charm, Can you please specify what is the difference of having `autofocus` attribute vs using `useRef` in react? since to make `useRef` work in a dynamically rendered component like React Modal, it takes some work, instead using autofocus it achieved the needed result with no hassle, thanks in advance

Comment: Nice one! this actually works good

Comment: For React Bootstrap 5 modals, you don't need to disable anything. https://react-bootstrap.github.io/docs/components/modal/#focus-on-specific-element.

Answer (score 6):

What worked for me is setting input's focus after the modal finishes transitioning in.

Using `useRef` hook, my code was like

```
...
<Modal ... onEntered={() => textarea.current.focus()} >
    <textarea  ... ref={textarea} />
</Modal>
```

Link to `Modal` API https://react-bootstrap.github.io/components/modal/#modal-props

Comment: Thank you!  So simple and so hard to find!

Comment: `autoFocus` attribute is supposed to work with react-bootstrap, unfortunately it doesn't if animation is enabled: https://github.com/react-bootstrap/react-bootstrap/issues/5102

Answer (score 3):

Just add autoFocus = {false} on modal and autoFocus = {true} on input.

```
<Modal autoFocus={false}>
  <Form>
    <ModalHeader>Type Your Input</ModalHeader>
    <ModalBody>
      <Input autoFocus={true} />
      <Button>Submit</Button>
    </ModalBody>
  </Form>
</Modal>
```

Ref: https://simplernerd.com/js-reactstrap-modal-autofocus/

Comment: This simple answer worked excellent for my use case. Thanks!